# How to convert a txt file to csv file in cells

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert a txt file in the following format:

```
NOTE
Date : 2/12/2019
Name : SomeName
Amount : 9000.0
Total : 59000.0
3ABA2363F5305877265757265784B2EB94ABxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

To a csv file, omitting `NOTE` and in cell format:

```
Date,Name,Amount,Total,Signature
2/12/2019, SomeName,9000,59000,3ABA2363F5305877265757265784B2EB94ABxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

What i have archived to do so far is:

```
Date,Number,Amount,Total,Signature
['NOTE'],"['Date', '2/12/2019']","['Name', 'SomeName']","['Amount', '9000.0']","['Total', '59000.0']",['3ABA2363F5305877265757265784B2EB94ABxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']
```

Here is my code:

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = [line.replace(":","").split() for line in in_file]
    zipped = zip([stripped]*1)
    with open('out_file.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('Date', 'Number', 'Amount', 'Total', 'Signature'))
        for group in zipped:
            writer.writerows(group)
```

Comment: You want `writerow`, not `writerows`.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: to convert a txt file to csv file in cells

Example using `csv.DictWriter`.

```
import io, csv

TXT = """NOTE
Date : 2/12/2019
Name : SomeName
Amount : 9000.0
Total : 59000.0
3ABA2363F5305877265757265784B2EB94ABxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NOTE
Date : 2/12/2019
Name : SomeName
Amount : 9000.0
Total : 59000.0
3ABA2363F5305877265757265784B2EB94ABxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
"""

with io.StringIO(TXT) as in_file,\
    io.StringIO() as out_file:

    fieldnames = ['Date', 'Name', 'Amount', 'Total', 'Signature']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    while True:
        data = {}
        for row in range(6):
            try:
                line = next(in_file)
                s = line.rstrip().split(':')

                if len(s) == 2:
                    data[s[0].strip()] = s[1].strip()
                else:
                    data['Signature'] = s[0]

            except StopIteration:
                break

        if data:
            writer.writerow(data)
        else:
            break

    print('{}'.format(out_file.getvalue()))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Date,Name,Amount,Total,Signature
> 2/12/2019,SomeName,9000.0,59000.0,3ABA2363F5305877265757265784B2EB94ABxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> 2/12/2019,SomeName,9000.0,59000.0,3ABA2363F5305877265757265784B2EB94ABxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How does the format change? (Like what are possible changes).

```
import csv
with open('inp', 'r') as in_file:
    dic = dict()
    a = []
    for line in in_file:
        a.append(line.replace(":","").split())

    a.pop(0) #NOTE
    last = a.pop().pop() #no key
    for i in a:
        dic[i[0]] = i[1]
    with open('out_file.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(dic.keys())
        toWrite = list(dic.values())
        toWrite.append(last)
        writer.writerow(toWrite)
```

To add "signature" into the first line you need to change `dic.keys()` into list and append a string to it (like in case of values with the last item)

Or  like this:

```
import csv
with open('inp', 'r') as in_file:
    a = []
    for line in in_file:
        a.append(line.replace(":","").split())

    a.pop(0) #NOTE
    with open('out_file.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('Date', 'Number', 'Amount', 'Total', 'Signature'))
        toWrite = []
        for i in a:
            toWrite.append(i.pop())
        writer.writerow(toWrite)
```

Comment: Thanks, so Its always going to be txt. btw, any idea adding a signature title to the last cell?

Comment: Yes, it could go in the same manner as the last item (sorry missed that at first)